# Error installing @solana/web3.js

Tags: web3.js

I am on WSL and working on the Hello World program. I am not able to install @solana/web3.js. The command I am using is
"npm install --save @solana/web3.js"

I am getting the below error -

npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node failed, reason:
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Am I getting this error because I am on WSL. I am not sure what I should change in config or how to change it.
Could anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.